# Problema con reader c# & access

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

Tengo esta sección de mi código para buscar todos los registros que necesito entre las fechas 1-28 de cada mes solo que al momento de ejecutar muestra información que no existe, en este caso no tengo registros después de mayo y el reader sigue trabajando hasta hasta diciembre copiando lo que tenia mayo en este caso ejemplificado se ve así:

`Abril 100
Mayo 200
Junio 200
Julio 200
Agosto 200`

y sigue escribiendo 200 hasta diciembre, finalmente no se donde esta mi error espero alguien me brinde un consejo o punto de vista

```
private void fillGraph() {
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=DB\\DB.mdb";
        int mesC = 0;
        List<decimal> Anual = new List<decimal>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
        {
            mesC = i;
            connection.Open();
            string sQue = "Select * from [Cuentas pagadas] where [Dia pago] between #1/" + Convert.ToString(mesC + 1) + "/2016# AND #28/" + Convert.ToString(mesC + 1) + "/2016# AND [Concepto]='" + cActual + "' ";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sQue, connection);
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<decimal> sumaMes = new List<decimal>();
            sumaMes.Clear();
            string t = "";
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                t = reader["Monto Pagado"].ToString();
                sumaMes.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(t));
            }
            if (sumaMes.Count > 0)
            {
                decimal Total = 0;
                for (int e = 0; e <= sumaMes.Count - 1; e++)
                {
                    Total += sumaMes[e];

                }
                Anual.Add(Total);
                connection.Close();
            }
            else {
                Anual.Add(0);
                connection.Close();
            }
                      }
        connection.Close();
        DateTimeFormatInfo mes = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
        int mesG = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
        {
            mesG = i;
            chBalance.Series["Fruc"].Points.AddXY(mes.GetMonthName(mesG + 1),Anual[i]);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Encontre el problema, Formato de la fecha a access es MM/DD/YYYY si alguien se encontrase con este problema en el futuro

Comment: Hizo que eso es la Respuesta, tambien.

Comment: @CarlosGarcia: cargalo como una respuesta para que ya le quede a otro y la pregunta quede como respondida. Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Adaptado del [comentario del OP, Carlos García](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8988/problema-con-reader-c-access#comment15943_8988)

El problema era el formato de la fecha, el cual en microsoft access es:

> MM/DD/YYYY